# CouchDb - get current _rev for a 409

Tags: couchdb

Is there some super secret nice flag to use in conjunction with PUT against CouchDb, so that an eventual 409 (Conflict) will include the current `_rev` in the response? Either in the body or as a header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't possible. The best thing you can do is a get request with an ETag header before the get. If the version is still current, you'll get a `304 Not Modified` status back. If it has been modifed, you'll get the new version. However, in either case, that does *not* guarantee that you won't get a `409 Conflict` on a subsequent `PUT`, because the document could have been modified in the meantime.

Comment: Well, doing another `GET` doesn't "feel" correct, since it (as you say) may not guarantee anything, and I already did a `GET` to get the doc in the first place. Sure I could add logic looking at timestamps to see if it probably is worth doing another one. No, I think it's more correct to in that case let it become a 409. But thanks.

Comment: Btw, even if the 409 response provided you with the latest _rev, that still wouldn't guarantee that the next PUT request with that _rev wouldn't create another 409...

Comment: No, but it will at least save me from doing a HEAD or GET for getting the latest known _rev.